# map only selected fields to the other object

Tags: java

I have two classes A and B, both classes have n number of fields. I need to map only specific fields from object of A to B using Streams API. I have only getters and setters in both classes and I don't have possibility of making changes in class A and B.

```
class A {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String city;
}

class B {
    private String name;
    private String country;
}
```

I have a bunch of A object in an ArrayList. I need to create List of object B and the object should have only value for name field.

I have similar buisness use case, where I will be I will be having n number of fields and I need to map multiple fileds.

Below code which I have tried,

```
private List<B> mapAtoB(List<A> a) {
    return a.stream().map(m -> mapToB(m)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private B mapToB(A a) {
    B b = new B();
    b.setName(a.getName());
    return b;
}
```

Is there any best solution to achieve, other than the above impl or create and map using constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to map between classes is using a mapping library like `MapStruct`.

In case you still wanna do it manually then you can using reflection and [FieldUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.9/index.html?org/apache/commons/lang3/reflect/FieldUtils.html) from the Apache Commons Lang 3:

```java
  public List<Obj2> mapObj1toObj2(List<Obj1> source) {
    return source.stream().map(obj1 -> {
      Obj2 obj2 = new Obj2();
      Arrays.asList(obj1.getClass().getDeclaredFields()).forEach(field -> {
        try {
          FieldUtils.writeField(obj2, field.getName(), FieldUtils.readField(field, obj1, true), true);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      });
      return obj2;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
```